# Get index value from function calling in onChange input element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, onchange

I am developing an application in React. I have a parent element wherein I have a child component(Photo) which needs to rendered multiple times(7 in below case). So I have used .map and allPhotos variable is rendered in return function.

Parent Component :

```
handlePhotos = (event, isSingleMulti, photoIndex) => {
    console.log("Upload Photo", event.target.files, photoIndex, isSingleMulti);
}
openFileDialog(isSingleMulti, photoIndex) {
    isSingleMulti === 'M' ? document.getElementById('multi-photo-input').click() : document.getElementById('single-photo-input').click();
}

let photosTemp = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
let allPhotos = photosTemp.map(ele => {

    return <Photo key={ele} photoBoxID={ele} openFileDialog={this.openFileDialog} handlePhotos={this.handlePhotos} onDeletePhoto={this.onDeletePhoto}/>
});
```

In my Child component (Photo) I have a div, onClick of div I call openFileDialog which internally calls click of hidden input element(#single-photo-input). onChange of input element I call handlePhotos. Both of these functions handlePhotos and openFileDialog are defined in my parent and passed to Child (Photo) as a prop.

Now what I need is that when onChange method handlePhotos is called, I want to return each Photo photoBoxID value. Basically, I want to check which Photo component was clicked. But every time I get value as 1 instead of respective 1,2,3 etc. What wrong am I doing?

Child Component :

```
const UploadImage = (props) => {
    console.log(props.photoBoxID);

    return (
    <div className="photo-root">
        <div className="photo-inner-container" onClick={() => props.openFileDialog('S')}>
            <span className="inner-text">+</span>
            <form encType="multipart/form-data" id="single-photo-form">
                <input type="file" name="file" id="single-photo-input" className="hide" accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png" 
                onChange={(event) => props.handlePhotos(event, 'S', props.photoBoxID)}/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}

class Photo extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            true === true ? <UploadImage {...this.props}/> : <ImagePreview {...this.props}/>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: you are not passing photoBoxId to props.openFileDialog('S').

Comment: @eramit2010 Thanks. I can pass that, but I am not sure how to pass it further on to document.getElementById('single-photo-input').click(); method call. And once i pass to onclick of input, will it be available in onChange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In open dialog, you are getting element by id but you don't have unique ids so you can append index to your input ids and pass index to openDialog function and click that particular input only.

Parent component

```
handlePhotos = (event, isSingleMulti, photoIndex) => {
    console.log("Upload Photo", event.target.files, photoIndex, isSingleMulti);
}
openFileDialog(isSingleMulti, photoIndex) {
    isSingleMulti === 'M' ? document.getElementById(`multi-photo-input-${photoIndex}`).click() : document.getElementById(`single-photo-input-${photoIndex}`).click(); //appended index here
}

let photosTemp = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
let allPhotos = photosTemp.map(ele => {

    return <Photo key={ele} photoBoxID={ele} openFileDialog={this.openFileDialog} handlePhotos={this.handlePhotos} onDeletePhoto={this.onDeletePhoto}/>
});
```

in your photo.js

```
const UploadImage = (props) => {
    console.log(props.photoBoxID);

    return (
    <div className="photo-root">
        <div className="photo-inner-container" onClick={() => props.openFileDialog('S', props.photoBoxID)}>
            <span className="inner-text">+</span>
            <form encType="multipart/form-data" id={`single-photo-form-${props.photoBoxID}`}>
                <input type="file" name="file" id={`single-photo-input-${props.photoBoxID}`} className="hide" accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png" 
                onChange={(event) => props.handlePhotos(event, 'S', props.photoBoxID)}/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}

class Photo extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            true === true ? <UploadImage {...this.props}/> : <ImagePreview {...this.props}/>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks It worked. Just wanted to know if this is a recommended way or good approach?

Comment: openDialog and handlePhotos are doing only these things you could move them to child component so you don't need to pass index and also you can use react refs instead of doing document.getElementById which is usually not a recommanded way.

Comment: Right. I can use that. Will change it. Was going old native approach. My bad

Answer (score 1):

#### Child Component :

```js
// as is
<div className="photo-inner-container" onClick={() => props.openFileDialog('S')}>

// to be
<div className="photo-inner-container" onClick={(event) => props.openFileDialog(event, 'S')}>
```

#### Parent Component :

```js
// as is
openFileDialog(isSingleMulti, photoIndex) {
    isSingleMulti === 'M' ? document.getElementById('multi-photo-input').click() : document.getElementById('single-photo-input').click();
}

// to be
openFileDialog = (event, isSingleMulti) => {
      isSingleMulti === 'M' ? document.getElementById('multi-photo-input').click() : event.currentTarget.childNodes[1].children[0].click();
}
```

Hmmm...
I tried to find another way to catch the exact input a client clicks lol